# How to move part of a div/span to new line?

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 50px; }

.wide-container, .narrow-container {
  flex: none;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px #c2c2c2 solid; 
}

.wide-container {
  width: 600px; 
}

.narrow-container {
  width: 300px; 
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 0; 
}

.text {
  flex: none;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  background-color: salmon;
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wide-container">
    <div class="flex"><span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="narrow-container">
    <div class="flex"><span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to apply some styles to piece of a text, and it should be inside of a flex box, because I need some of its features. The problem is that when there is not enough space, text will overflow:

[image]

So, I need to split text somehow, to keep the styling on a new line like this (did it manually here):
[image]

UPD:
Thanks for the answers, but the problem is a little bit more complex than it looks at first glance. Solution in answers (so far) leads to this result:

[image]

Which means that line breaks inside of a .text container. If you compare this result with the result I need (screenshot above), you will understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use word-break:break-all; or word-break: break-word;

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 50px; }

.wide-container, .narrow-container {
  flex: none;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px #c2c2c2 solid; 
}

.wide-container {
  width: 600px; 
}

.narrow-container {
  width: 300px; 
}

.flex {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex:none;
  gap: 10px 0; 
}

.text {
  flex: none;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  line-height:35px;
  background-color: salmon;
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wide-container">
    <div class="flex"><span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="narrow-container">
    <div class="flex">
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.     3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: გამარჯობა! Yeah, it is almost did the trick, but as we can see it won't respect the paddings or flex gaps :(

Comment: you can use line-height check above snippet i changed css

Answer (score -1):

Remove flex from text class and it will work.

```
.text {
  padding: 5px 2px;
  background-color: salmon;
  color: white; 
}
```

https://codepen.io/IChoseTheRedPill/pen/zYaRjZb

Comment: Not quite :( Please check the update in question

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description you are looking for the `</br>` HTML element. Just added a `</br>` in your example.

However, removing `flex: none` from your .text class is a much more elegant solution to your problem, as suggested [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532845/17751007).

In addition, to get the "highlight" effect that you want you can't apply a `background-color` to the whole .text class.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 50px; }

.wide-container, .narrow-container {
  flex: none;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px #c2c2c2 solid; 
}

.wide-container {
  width: 600px; 
}

.narrow-container {
  width: 300px; 
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 0; 
}

.text {
  padding: 5px 2px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white; 
}

.highlight {
  background-color: salmon;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wide-container">
    <div class="flex"><span class="text"><span class="highlight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </span></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="narrow-container">
    <div class="flex"><span class="text"><span class="highlight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, </span><span class="highlight">adipisicing elit.</span></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite :( Please check the update in question

Comment: It wasn't described clearly. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: What was your update? I see that you manually split the text into two spans, but this is not a solution :(

Answer (score -1):

This worked correctly for me when flex was disabled

```
  .text {
    background-color: salmon;
    color: white;
    line-height: 2em!important;
    padding: 3px 0px;
 }
```